# converting JSON attributes response to BOOL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

If I have a JSON response as follows:

```
 "is_following": false,
```

how can I convert this to a BOOL in objective-C?

this doesn't seem to be right:

```
 [[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)[profileData valueForKey:@"is_following"]] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on JSON parser you use. For example, in case of using TouchJSON you can just call `boolValue` on the parsed object: `[[profileData objectForKey:@"is_following"] boolValue]`

Comment: From the JSONKit documentation: 'true' and 'false' primitive types are mapped to NSNumber. So this solution should work.

Comment: It seems JSONKit doesn't treat @1 or @0 as the same as [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES|NO], when it's the latter JSONKit will convert correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because `-valueForKey` returns an object (`id`), and `BOOL` is an alias for `signed char`, you can simply call `-intValue` on the result:

```
BOOL asBool = [[profileData valueForKey:@"is_following"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call `-boolValue` directly?

```
[profileData objectForKey:@"is_following"] boolValue]
```

Any JSON framework will convert that JSON `false` value into an `NSNumber*`. And in fact `NSString*` also responds to `-boolValue`, so in the case of a brain-dead JSON source emitting `"false"` you're still covered. However if the JSON contains `null` or any container type then you'll have a problem, so you'll probably want to double-check what class the value actually is.

*Note, I used `-objectForKey:` instead of `-valueForKey:`, because if this is JSON then `profileData` must be an `NSDictionary*`. `-objectForKey:` is the correct method to use to extract data from `NSDictionaries`.